# Next js started take me error related with different modules

Tags: npm, webpack, next.js, node-modules

Next js started take me error related with different modules.

```
 ⨯ ./node_modules/@swc/helpers/esm/_interop_require_wildcard.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@swc/helpers/esm/_interop_require_wildcard.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js
```

or

```
Module not found: C:\Projects\TodolistByDay\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react\package.json (directory description file): ...
```

or

```
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
    at _0x4fdcb3.read (c:\Users\Destr\.vscode\extensions\wallabyjs.console-ninja-1.0.292\out\buildHook\index.js:1144:70286
```

Various modules are constantly failing and printing various errors.
Also print warning webpack: `[webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Restoring pack failed from C:\Projects\TodolistByDay\frontend\.next\cache\webpack\client-development.pack.gz: Error: incorrect header check ...`

I cannot explain the reason for this errors.
Maybe you need a specify code?

I try:

- remove node_modules folder and run `npm i`.
- remove .next folder for clean the cache and run `npm run dev`
- updated next package in package.json (from 14.1.0 to 14.1.4)
- updated errored modules